Free-Surface kinematic BC - Azimuthal suspended flow - cylindrical coordinates - How to define the free surface and derive its impermeability?
I am working on a linear stability analysis of an azimuthal free surface flow. However, I am stuck in the derivation of the kinematic BC to apply for the impermeability of the azimuthal free surface (see Figure Schematic). In my understanding (correct me if wrong), such kinematic impermeability condition should stem from imposing the material derivative of the geometrical definition of the free surface equal to zero.
$$
\frac{D}{Dt} (H(x,y,t)) = \partial_t H +\nabla H \cdot \vec{u} = 0
$$
In Cartesian coordinates with a flat free surface $H(x,y,t)=y-\eta(x,t)$
this kinematic conditions boils down to enforce the normal velocity of the fluid equal to the normal velocity of the interface ($\textbf{u}\cdot \textbf{n}=\textbf{U}\cdot \textbf{n}$).  (I believe that in a similar question this is indeed obtained with the material derivative Fluid Dynamics, free surface boundary condition derivation.).
What happens if I want to describe the azimuthal free surface of Figure Schematic in cylindrical coordinates?
I tried to describe the azimuthal free surface of Figure Schematic in cylindrical coordinates. I define a surface as $H(x,y,t)=r-\eta(\theta,t)$. Thus, the material derivative is $\partial_t H +\nabla H \cdot \vec{u}=0 $ with $\nabla H=(1,-1/r \partial_\theta \eta )$ and $\vec {u} =(u_r,u_\theta)$. Hence I obtain
$$
-\partial_t \eta + u_r + u_\theta (-\frac{\partial_\theta \eta}{r}) =0
$$
I am having doubts...

Am I conceptually correct to try to obtain the kinematic free surface BC in this way? - I think so

Is $H(x,y,t)=r-\eta(\theta,t)$ correct to describe the cylindrical free surface of  Figure Schematic? - I am less sure about it.


Further Normal Modes Analysis and Linearisation
Then I try to derive further the final condition I need to apply to solve the stability problem by 1. flow decomposition: base flow + perturbation (expressed via stream function) 2. normal modes for the perturbation and 3. linearisation a the free surface location)

Is this correct to linearise in this way about $r=r_0$? I think it will be important to change variable for the base flow $\bar{v}_\theta$  conveniently and consistently with such linearisation at the free surface.

